# Jquery Datatable - Pulling data from server - how to use value as a attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a simple code to pull data using ajax in my datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
    "pageLength": 50,
    "ajax": "/test/pull/",

    "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 6,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-sm\" onclick>Click</button>"
    } ],

     "columns": [
        { "data": "a" },
        { "data": "b" },
        { "data": "c" },
        { "data": "d" },
        { "data": "r" },
        { "data": "f" }
    ]

} );
```

I am pulling from server one more column - g and I would like to add this value as a new attribute ( for example ID ) to a button named "Click".

Was trying to find anything in google but unsuccessfully - will be thankful for your support

Thanks in advance,

Comment: check [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html), you just need to render the button as html and add the id property from your data in the row

Comment: works perfect, thanks a lot